# Function return for another Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Edit:**
How can I `return` a value for a parent `function`?

```
function returningFn() {
    function otherFn() {
        var value = 123;
        return value; //For returningFn     
    }
}
```

I would like `returningFn` to return the `value`... How do I do this??? I can't get it to work...

Comment: What doesn't work (i.e., what error do you get)?

Comment: Also, when you initially call the function, you're not passing in a parameter. If that matters...

Comment: You are returning the parameter to your function, which is nothing because you don't pass one.

Comment: Your code example makes no sense and if you were to call the otherFn(), you would be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: What are you *trying* to return?

Comment: You're doing a recursive call that is supposed to return a function, which it will never exit first off, not to mention you're returning the `returninfo` arguement. Makes absolutely no sense with the question in hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function returningFn(returnInfo) {
    function otherFn() {
        var value = 123;
        return value;  //return the value
    }
    return otherFn();  //call the function which has its own return statement
}   
console.log( returningFn() );
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aVU8/)

Answer (score 3):

```
function returningFn() {
    function otherFn() {
        var value = 123;
        return value; //For returningFn     
    }
    return otherFn();
}
```

What you had before wasn't referencing the right stuff. When a JS function returns something you can treat the function call as whatever it returns so you could:

```
alert(returningFn());
```